# how do I break up long words in my Django project?

Tags: html, css, django

so I have a username on my site that's overflowing out of the content box [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I7D5.png)

so I thought `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { color: #44444 overflow-wrap: break-word;}`.
would help but that it didn't

[the code for the profile page is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMzEs.png)

all CSS for the profile page works except for the overflow. if anyone could help me I would appreciate it :)

Comment: Really long user names like this simply will never wrap. Try using `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;` which will make it truncate the end of the string so the end result will be something like, "Testingname12345..."

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for django based solution you can use built in `truncatechars` template tag. It will truncate the username if it is longer than specified characters. For example If username is *Testingname123456789*, it will display it as  *Testingname1234…*

```
<div class="media-body">
    <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username | truncatechars:15 }}</h2>
</div>
```

Reference - [truncatechars template tag - Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I will keep this as an option but I don’t think I like it when your username gets cut short.